# Python Pandas, How to replace values that have a count smaller than X

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's an example:

```
    A    
0   V1 
1   V1 
2   V2 
3   v4  
4   v4 
5   v7
```

And I would want to end up with something like this:

```
    A    
0   V1 
1   V1 
2   np.NaN 
3   v4  
4   v4 
5   np.NaN
```

Basically it would be something like this:

```
df.A[df.A.value_counts() < 2] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `transform`, and then index with `loc` -

```
df.loc[df.groupby('A').A.transform('count').lt(2), 'A'] = np.nan    
df

     A
0   V1
1   V1
2  NaN
3   v4
4   v4
5  NaN
```

Comment: @BryceSoker No problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then check values of index by[`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) :

```
a = df.A.value_counts()
m = df.A.isin(a.index[a<2])
print (m)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

df.loc[m, 'A'] = np.NaN
print (df)
     A
0   V1
1   V1
2  NaN
3   v4
4   v4
5  NaN
```